# How to handle method is abstract, but not declare in DEX file proguard warning

Tags: android, proguard

I enable proguard on my project, it keeps warning like

`[methodName] is abstract, but the declaring class is neither abstract nor an interface in dex file [path_to_dex_file/base.apk]`.

What is the cause of warning and how to deal with it?